# Child entity does not get saved when parent entity saved . why?

Tags: java, spring

I have a **FilterEvent class** like below

```
public class FilterEvent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer filterId;
    @NotNull
    private String userId;
    @NotNull
    private String columnId;
    private String columnName;
    private String operator;
    private String filterValue;
    //@Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(255) DEFAULT 'filter'")
    @ColumnDefault("'frequency'")
    private String filterType;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "dataset_id")
    private Dataset dataset;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "prep_id")
    private Preparation preparation;
}
```

And i mapped this class with Preparation class with **`@ManyToOne`**

My Preparation class looks like below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "preparation")
public class Preparation {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "prep_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long prepId;
    @Column(name = "prep_name")
    private String prepName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "preparation", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<FilterEvent> filterEvents;
}
```

And when i  tried to update the **`filterEvents`** during save of preparation as below , the filterEvents are not get saved in **FilterEvent** table .

```
public Preparation savePreparation(Integer datasetId, Preparation preparation) throws DatasetNotFoundException {
    LOGGER.trace("PreparationService : inside addPreparation");
    Dataset dataset = datasetRepository.findById(datasetId).get();
    if (null == dataset) {
        throw new DatasetNotFoundException(Integer.toString(datasetId));
    }
    preparation.setDataset(dataset);
    preparation.setUserId(dataset.getUserId());
    Set<FilterEvent> filterEvents = preparation.getFilterEvents();
    if(null!=filterEvents) {
        filterEvents.stream().forEach(f -> f.setFilterId(null));
    }

    preparationRepository.save(preparation);
    Long prepId = preparation.getPrepId();
    return preparationRepository.findById(prepId).get();

}
```

Why it is happening ?
The need to save **filterEvents** in the **FilterTable** , When i save a preparation . Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: Activate showing sql to see running queries and post them here.

Answer (score 1):

Change FilterEvent class property to cascade type ALL.as you have mentioned PERSIST.

```
public class FilterEvent {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer filterId;
@NotNull
private String userId;
@NotNull
private String columnId;
private String columnName;
private String operator;
private String filterValue;
//@Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(255) DEFAULT 'filter'")
@ColumnDefault("'frequency'")
private String filterType;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "dataset_id")
private Dataset dataset;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "prep_id")
private Preparation preparation;}
```

Comment: Not working with CascadeType.ALL also. Do i need to drop table and restart ? @GauravRai1512

Comment: No, are you getting any error and which entity you want to save with FilterEvent class? you want to update both or any specific?

Comment: When i m saving Preparation i need to save entries into FilterEvent table as well . But in FilterEvent table no entries are getting saved eventthough the preparation is saved.

Comment: might be possible while fetching Set<FilterEvent> filterEvents = preparation.getFilterEvents(); this value you were getting null.

Comment: so you also have to create else block and create an entry? and why are you setting null in setFilterId as this is primary key right?Debug your code on this point.

Comment: I have @GenerationType.AUTO so need to set null to insert as a new entry in the table

Comment: i hope you would have mentioned the foriegn key mapping in between both tabel also you have created auto generator so when you will save your data it will save in your child table as well on the basis of foriegn key mapping and auto generator will automatically generate a new primary id for child table.